# Passar cada resultado de um array para uma variável

Tags: php

Tenho esse laço que lista todas as linhas do *array*, mas preciso só de alguma linhas. Como passar cada resultado para uma variável?

```
$WS->key='00000000000';  // Atenção: Este parâmetro possui valores diferentes 

// Chamada do método e retorno da resposta.
$response=$WS->getInfo($param); // Esta função da classe WS_API retorna um objeto  
$control_sign=array();
$control_sign=$WS->getResponse('getInfo',$response);

foreach ($response as $name => $value) {
    echo $name .''. $value;
}

// Resultado
//   shopId         33015842
//   paymentMethod  E_COMMERCE
//   contractNumber 1026194250
//    Nome          Fabio

// Código com as Sugestões do Amigos
foreach ($response as $name => $value) {
    echo $linha = "{$name}{$value}";
    echo"<br>";
}

extract($response);
echo $amount;
```

Quero que seja retornado apenas as linhas *shopId* e *paymentMethod*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode filtrar as informações da *array* impondo condições, somente se a chave for *shopId* ou *paymentMethod*, você imprime. Veja um exemplo:

```
$response = array('shopId' => 33015842,
                  'paymentMethod' => 'E_COMMERCE',
                  'contractNumber' => 1026194250,
                  'Nome' => 'Fabio');

foreach ($response as $chave => $valor) {
    if ($chave == 'shopId' or $chave == 'paymentMethod'){
        echo "{$chave} {$valor} <br>";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/xyRwlm)</kbd>

**Atualização**: O `foreach` não era necessário. Para obter os valores de um [**objeto**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), acesse usando a sintaxe [`->`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/sdo.sample.getset.php). Veja um exemplo:

```
$response = (object) array('shopId' => 33015842,
                  'paymentMethod' => 'E_COMMERCE',
                  'contractNumber' => 1026194250,
                  'Nome' => 'Fabio');

$shopId = $response->shopId;
$paymentMethod = $response->paymentMethod;
$contractNumber = $response->contractNumber;

echo "{$shopId}\n";
echo "{$paymentMethod}\n";
echo "{$contractNumber}\n";
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/cGIIZt)</kbd>

Comment: Ok quase isso.... mais eu preciso é que casa linha, passe para uma variavel para poder manipular cada uma.

Comment: @FabioHenrique Ali onde tem o `echo ..` você pode usar uma variável e concatenar a chave e valor assim: `$linha = "{$chave}{$valor}";`, daí basta usar a variável `linha`.

Comment: Ola Amigo desculpa a ignorância mais sou novo nisso ainda não funcionou por por estar em um loop não consigo declarar as variaveis alterei o codigo inicial mostrando como esta meu array original

Comment: Mais o que eu preciso é algo do tipo $var1 = $linha . "<br>"; $var2 = $linha . "<br>";... ou  $var1 = $linha["os"];

Comment: eu precisaria de variaveismesmo poderia ser até fora foreach

Comment: nesse modelo o codigo ficaria muito grande pois deve ter mais de 30 linhas. Eu preciso so dos valores   no caso algo como extract($resposta); resolveria mais não ta funcionando

Comment: como eu precisava http://pastebin.com/sJ1LLuHK

Comment: @FabioHenrique Deu para entender agora. =) Veja se é isso: http://ideone.com/5pDqGi

Comment: Isso mesmo essa é a ideia mais deu erro Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @FabioHenrique `$response` é um **objeto** certo? tente fazer assim: `$shopId = $response->shopId;`, `$paymentMethod = $response->paymentMethod;`, etc.

Comment: Perfeito... Não Posso nem colocar Meus agradecimentos aqui Mais era isso mesmo....

Answer (score 3):

O que você pode fazer é utilizar a função [extract](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php) do PHP.

> Esta função trata chaves como nome de variáveis e valores com os valores da variáveis. Para cada par chave/valor ela cria uma variável na atual tabela de símbolo, seguindo os parâmetros extract_type e prefix.

```
extract($resposta);
echo $shopId;
echo $paymentMethod; //...
```

Bem, acredito que essa seja a solução que você precisa para mandar os valores da array para variáveis. É mais conveniente que o foreach tanto pela praticidade de implementação quanto pela velocidade de execução.

<kbd>[**EXEMPLO**](http://ideone.com/fPHrrC)</kbd>

Comment: Realmente ficaria melhor fora do foreach mais ainda não funcionou alterei o codigo inicial mostrando como esta meu array original.

Comment: Função interessante. *+1*. Nesse caso como `$resposta` é um objeto, é necessário converte-lo para *array*, [exemplo](http://ideone.com/zTMNq8).

Comment: Acabei de ver a atualização... Basta fazer um cast `extract((array)$resposta)` do mesmo modo que fez no objeto.